# Remove element in the set while iterating

Tags: kotlin

I have the following scenario:
In the details variable, I need to remove a course from the mutable set of courses, for each student based on a condition.

If I remove as I have done below, I get concurrent modification exception, because I am modifying the variable while iterating through it.

How can I iterate the map in reverse so that it doesn't throw the deadlock, or is there a better way to handle this scenario ?

```kotlin
val details = MutableMap<Student, MutableSet<CourseDetail>>

details?.forEach { student, courses ->
    courses?.forEach { course ->
       if (b?.contains(course) == false) {
           details[student]?.remove(course)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You should use a [Mutable Iterator](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-iterator/) It allows the `remove` operation inside the cycle

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you just want

```
for (courses in details.values) {
  courses.retainAll(b)
}
```

(Notably, you should also avoid null collections so you don't have to scatter `?.` everywhere.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use ConcurrentHashMap and ConcurrentHashSet it provide thread safety
or

simply use iterator to remove element while iterating

```
details?.forEach { student, courses ->
    Iterator<CourseDetail> itr = courses.iterator();
    while (itr.hasNext())
        if (b?.contains(itr.next()) == false) itr.remove();
 }
```